# Barra de Notificação Assumir cor de fundo do app usando Delphi

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey

Como fazer para a barra de notificação assumir uma cor pré determinada como por exemplo no whattsup, gmail etc.

Uso a IDE de programação Delphi Firemonkey.

Nos meus apps a barra sempre assume a cor preta, segue exemplo.

[image: Esse é meu aplicativo]

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/material/theme.html), você precisa mudar a `colorPrimaryDark` existe diversas formas de fazer, você pode criar seu próprio tema ou modificar o existente, pode implementar no XML ou na auto-criação do formulário.

Segue exemplos:

**values/themes.xml:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>
```

**ou no Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Aqui um bom [material](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/) de estudo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas preciso fazer estas alterações usando Delphi, existe alguma forma de fazer via programação ?