# Material design status bar android delphi-10

Tags: android, delphi-10

Existe alguma forma ou algum style para mudar a cor da status bar do smartphone Android como material design atual no Delphi?

A imagem abaixo exemplifica o que pretendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105652/barra-de-notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-assumir-cor-de-fundo-do-app-usando-delphi

Comment: o problema e que quando altero o xml toda vez que compilo a aplicação ele altera pro jeito que era antes